# Declare a (int) variable and pass it to another activity

Tags: java, android

I have a Check Box and if it has been checked, an integer variable (result=0) is defined and passed to another activity.
how to do that ??

Comment: Do you want to start new activity when checkbox gets checked?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent secondIntent=new Intent(this,SecondClass.class);
secondIntent.putExtra("Name",yourvalue);
```

in SecondClass get the value like this

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("Name",-1);
```